# Calling a python script with ROSRUN

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have seen that you can call python scripts with rosrun, i.e.:

> rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py

and I have been trying to setup my project so that I can call a python script in the same way:

> rosrun myproject mypythonscript.py

following the structure of the tf2_tools project, I have created a folder named *scripts* in the *myproject*, but I can not yet call that script using rosrun.

What else do I have to do?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56640/calling-a-python-script-with-rosrun/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, make sure the python script is executable (`chmod +x mypythonscript.py`).

Next, make sure you have a shebang line at the top of the script that looks like `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-02-28**:
It works now, thank you! I did not had a blank at the shebang line >.<

**Comment by [Luczia](https://answers.ros.org/users/14356/luczia/) on 2015-01-17**:
For me, it was a problem of file format (between unix and dos format). Explainations [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10412/no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-rosrun/)
I ran the command : 'dod2unix mypythonscript.py' and the rosrun command did work then.